# Selenium WebDriverWait.until(invisiblityOfAllElements) returns timeout on NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code which waits for a time for element to disappear

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(elements));
```

Which internally calls Selenium's

```
isInvisible(WebElement element)
```

and isInvisible is defined as follows

```
try {
      return !element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ignored) {
      // We can assume a stale element isn't displayed.
      return true;
    }
```

**Note: It only catches StaleElementReferenceException**

and in `isDispalyed` when the element is referenced, `pagefactory` package's `ElementLocator` class's `findElement` is called  method which throws`NoSuchElementException`

This exception propogates to `FluentWait` class
Wherein

```
try {
        V value = isTrue.apply(input);
        if (value != null && (Boolean.class != value.getClass() || Boolean.TRUE.equals(value))) {
          return value;
        }

        // Clear the last exception; if another retry or timeout exception would
        // be caused by a false or null value, the last exception is not the
        // cause of the timeout.
        lastException = null;
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        lastException = propagateIfNotIgnored(e);
      }
```

The exception is caught by `Throwable`, and this causes the timeout and I am not able to check whether all elements have been disappeared from the screen

P.S.
All my Elements are defined by `@FindBy`
Example

```
@FindBy(css = ".myclass-name")
private WebElement myWorkspaceButton;
```

So cannot use `ExpectedConditions` method taking `By` as argument

Is there any other way to check if all the WebElements have disappeared from the screen?
Or
Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Guy It doesn't, I Found `NoSuchElementException is thrown by `DefaultLocator` class's `findElement` method from `pagefactory` package is called when the element is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write you own method for that in which you loop through all you elements and catch those exceptions.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOfAllElements(
        final List<WebElement> elements) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            for (WebElement element : elements) {
                try {
                    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException | NoSuchElementException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "invisibility of all elements " + elements;
        }
    };
}
```

I am not sure but probably you need to catch `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException` as well.

Comment: No it is not. The original version does not catch the `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Thanks, will try this approach and let you know :)

Comment: OP mentioned that `isDisplayed` calls `findElement` which causes the exception. He did not mention which implemenation of WebElement he uses (maybe his own?).

Answer (score -1):

Selenium's check for visibility/invisibility assumes that **elements are present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)** so the options are in:

1. Add another Explicit Wait to hold on until all the elements matching the locator query are absent like:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeLessThan(By.your_locator("your_query"),1));
   ```
2. You can supress the exception by providing the relevant [`ignoring`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#ignoring-java.lang.Class-) stanza like:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
           .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(elements));
   ```

More information:

- [WebDriver Advanced Usage: Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't have the By locator of the element as I used @FindBy annotation to located the element an am creating a generic function wherein I can pass any elements it will wait until all of them disappers in the given timeout,

Comment: Will try the 2nd option and will post the results

Comment: The exception is suppressed by the second option, but it still causes timeout and also this approach would not work for checking multiple elements to disappear